# toFixed(2) not rounding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `toFixed(2)`, but it does not round and I cannot find why?

form

```
<div class="col col-sm-2"><%= f.input :price, placeholder: "Price incl. VAT", label: false, input_html:{class: "field price"}  %></div>
<div class="col col-sm-2 "><%= f.input :amount, label: false, input_html:{class: "field quantity"} %></div>
<div class="col col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="field subtotal form-control"></div>
```

script

```
<script>
//on change
  $('.field').keyup(function() {
      var price = [];
      var quantity = [];

      $('.price').each(function(i, obj) {
          price.push(+obj.value);
      });

      $('.quantity').each(function(i, obj) {
          quantity.push(+obj.value);
      });

      console.log(price)
      console.log(quantity)

      var result = 0;

      price.map((o,i)=>{
      $(".subtotal").eq( i ).val(o*quantity[i]);
      result += o*quantity[i];
      });

      result = parseFloat(result).toFixed(2)

      $(".result").val(result);
  })

</script>
```

Comment: `Number.toFixed()` doesn't do [rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) to a nearest integer. It simply trims the precision to a defined level. You're probably looking for `Math.round(number)`.

Comment: Try Math.round(value * 100) / 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Number.prototype.toFixed()` does not round a number. Use `Math.round()` to do it. Also, `result` already has the type `Number`, so the `parseFloat` is pretty much useless. Instead of:

```
result = parseFloat(result).toFixed(2)
```

use:

```
result = Math.round(result);
```

As a side note, don't use `.map` as a substitute for `.forEach`, meaning that this:

```
price.map((o,i)=>{
  $(".subtotal").eq( i ).val(o*quantity[i]);
  result += o*quantity[i];
});
```

should be this:

```
price.forEach((o, i) => {
  $(".subtotal").eq( i ).val(o*quantity[i]);
  result += o*quantity[i];
});
```

Furthermore, I would suggest to query the DOM once instead of several times, because traversing the DOM is a rather heavyweight operation.

Comment: Thank you David, that worked. Also thank you for the tips on the code, as you probably guessed I'm still learning so these tips are more than welcome:)